Mock outgoing docker http requests on arbitrary port
I've written a service in docker that depends on other services. However, I have difficulty testing it, as I cannot automate any tests that verify the outgoing traffic of my docker container.
When my service receives a request, it does some number crunching. It's supposed to send the results to two other services. For testing purposes, I simply start a mock server locally which verifies that it received the result from my docker container.
The way I currently do this is by specifying extra_hosts in docker-compose, i.e.:
extra_hosts:
  - some-web-service.some-domain:127.0.0.1

Now, since this is http I am limited to starting my mock service on port 80?
What if I want to start several different mock services, or if I simply am already using port 80?
How can I redirect the outgoing traffic of my container to say port 1234?
Simply put, I want to be able to do this:
extra_hosts:
  - some-web-service.some-domain:127.0.0.1:1234


This doesn't seem to be Docker-specific; you'd test this the same way you would with any other setup.  If your HTTP library allows you to provide a transport adapter, for example, you can write a unit test that completely mocks the network flow without ever contacting the network.  There are also standard testing libraries in most languages that can run a mock HTTP service for you.

Sorry but that does not answer the question. Mocking HTTP services is not a problem, I can and have done that. The problem is mocking endpoints which a standalone docker container is targetting. These should be redirect towards the mock server and that is my question: how to do that without modifying the source code of the docker container? I am not sure this can be done easily, which is why I asked the question.

It's not clear where the mock service is running. You say locally - this could mean in the same container as a background process, as another service in docker, or on the host pc. The only way "127.0.0.1" would apply would be if you are running the mock service as a background process in the container. In the world of containers, "127.0.0.1" refers to the container itself, not the host os.
To reach a mock service running on your host system, substitute "host-gateway" for 127.0.0.1 - this alias represents the IP that is bridged from the container to the host. Also: as this IP is not 127.0.0.1 the mock service can not listen on localhost - traffic over this bridge does not count as localhost traffic.
  extra_hosts:
   - some-web-service.some-domain:host-gateway

If you can't redirect your app to use any port other than the default (80), well the bridge interface is just that, a bridge to your host - docker can not do any port remapping.
It would in that case be better to run your mock service as containers in your compose.
services:
  service-to-test:
    ...
    depends_on:
    - mock1
    - mock2

  mock1:
    image: mock1:tag
    build:
      context: ./mock1
    networks:
      default:
        aliases: ["api1.example.com"]

  mock2:
    image: mock2:tag
    networks:
      default:
        aliases: ["api2.example.com"]

Assuming you can dockerize your mocks, this will add dns bases aliases for each mock to the default network that the service under test is attached to, allowing it to connect to them. Make sure they are listening on port 80 as, again, docker networks allow direct service to service communication and there is no port remapping.
